# how to show/hide reply comment box on multiple displayed comments

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so here is the code i use this for me to show/hide the comment box it works actually but the problem i encounter when i make multiple comments when i tried to click the reply on the 1st comment the comment box show/hide but when i tried to click other comments it doesnt work anymore it only works on the first one.... is there any way to fix this?..

**HTML code**

```
<div id="replybutton" class="btn4 like" style="margin-top:-25px;margin-left:-10px;">
    <span class="btn reply" id="replyb">Reply</span> •&emsp;
</div>

<div class="col-lg-12" id="reply" style="background:#eff9c7;margin-left:50px;margin-top:-20px;display:none;" >
    <img  src="img/icons/no-icon-available.png" class="pull-left" style="   border-radius:50%;margin-bottom:3px;width:30px;height:30px;" />
    <p style="margin-top:18px;line-height:15px;"><strong class="font-1" style="margin-left:10px;">Hajime Sasota </strong> Sample comment<br>

<div class="btn4 disabled" style="margin-top:-25px;margin-left:-10px;">
    <span style="margin-left:5px;font-size:12px;color:gray;"><abbr class="timeago" title="">time</abbr></span>
</div>
</p>
<input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" style="width:88%;height:25px;margin-top:-10px;" placeholder="Write a reply..." />
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#replybutton').click(function(){
$('#reply').toggle();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: have you checked your `code`. If you are using this very same code, then there is a probability that you're repeating `reply` `ID's` on your page. And it could be a reason.

Comment: Your code seems ok to me, only an extra div and p needs to be removed, further you should post the code where do you have problem with multiple comments.

Comment: i only posted this code bc i think this is where i have a problem. and also my id reply is unique.  what happen is when user commented this field also added on the comment so basically every comment have this field.. but when i tried to click the reply it only works on the 1st one.. not on the other comments

Comment: This is happening because, you are binding click event only to one button `$('#replybutton').click`, you should bind click event to every new button or  refer @RohanKumar answer, to use a generic class to bind it once, and then use a suitable selector to find the element to be toggled.

Answer (score 1):

`id` must be unique in a HTML Page, you should change id to class `replybutton` and `reply` and jquery code would be,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.replybutton').click(function(){
       $(this).next('.reply').toggle();
    });
});
```

**Snippet,**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.replybutton').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.reply').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="replybutton btn4 like" style="">
    <span class="btn reply" id="replyb">Reply</span> •&emsp;
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-12 reply" style="display:none">
    <img src="img/icons/no-icon-available.png" class="pull-left" style="" />
    <p>
      <strong class="font-1" style="margin-left:10px;">Hajime Sasota </strong> Sample comment<br/>

      <div class="btn4" style="">
        <span style=""><abbr class="timeago" title="">time</abbr></span>
      </div>
    </p>
    <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" placeholder="Write a reply..." />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="replybutton btn4 like" style="">
    <span class="btn reply" id="replyb">Reply</span> •&emsp;
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-12 reply" style="display:none">
    <img src="img/icons/no-icon-available.png" class="pull-left" style="" />
    <p>
      <strong class="font-1" style="margin-left:10px;">Hajime Sasota </strong> Sample comment<br/>

      <div class="btn4" style="">
        <span style=""><abbr class="timeago" title="">time</abbr></span>
      </div>
    </p>
    <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" placeholder="Write a reply..." />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="replybutton btn4 like" style="">
    <span class="btn reply" id="replyb">Reply</span> •&emsp;
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-12 reply" style="display:none">
    <img src="img/icons/no-icon-available.png" class="pull-left" style="" />
    <p>
      <strong class="font-1" style="margin-left:10px;">Hajime Sasota </strong> Sample comment<br/>

      <div class="btn4" style="">
        <span style=""><abbr class="timeago" title="">time</abbr></span>
      </div>
    </p>
    <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" placeholder="Write a reply..." />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the id reply is unique... i even change it to class but it doesn't work either.

Comment: i edited my post sorry it has already have a class="col-md-12" i just got a typo there..but still the problem wasnt fixed yet i dont know why.. when i tried to change it to class the reply does not functioning anymore..

Comment: Don't use `class` attribute twice. See my updated answer and snippet.